# maven-resources-plugin:2.5 /checkRar.resource (Permission denied)

Tags: java, maven, maven-resources-plugin

I'm trying to build Maven project on my Mac by using Netbeans.
But I have some strange problems with maven-resources-plugin

It's returning "permission denied" on all my .resources files.

```
------------------------------------------------------------------------
BUILD FAILURE
------------------------------------------------------------------------
Total time: 3.588s
Finished at: Thu May 05 14:48:57 EEST 2016
Final Memory: 13M/223M
------------------------------------------------------------------------
Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:2.5:resources (default-resources) on project site_feemanok: /checkRar.resource (Permission denied) -> [Help 1]

To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
```

Comment: The resource given with a `/...` does not make sense...

Comment: @khmarbaise what you mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was just a permission problem, so I have just run Netbeans with sudo.